# C# - List files in directory given by a variable, include full path and delimiting with a comma

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to get a list of files in a folder, add the path and delimit each with a comma.

I can manage to get the files through

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Directory");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

and delimit it using

```
var result = string.Join(", ", (object[])Files);
```

but I can't get the full path included in it.

I can get the path and file name through

```
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Directory\", "*.txt");
```

But doesn't suit either as I want to use a variable for the path

I've tried using string builder but I can't figure out how to get that to work properly. I don't think it will work in this example?

Thanks in advance!

edit: my desired output is something like:

C:\Directory\myfile.txt, C:\Directory\anotherfile.txt, C:\Directory\A Differentfile.txt, C:\Directory\SomeOther File.txt, C:\Directory\textfile.txt

Comment: _want to use a variable for the path_ so what is different in the first example where you use a constant C:\directory from the second example where you use the same constant?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please [edit] it to include sample data and desired output.

Comment: I'm learning c# so my route is using this as something to build on. So when I get this working the next step is to pull the directory from streamreader as a variable. The second example can't pull in a variable? Unless I'm doing it wrong? @ZoharPeled Edited and desired output added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a specific string for each `FileInfo`, say, its [`FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx), use `Select` (add `using System.Linq` at the top of your program)

```
var result = string.Join(", ", Files.Select(f => f.FullName));
```